# how is using busybox possible without mounting /system first?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/system");

looking at updater-scripts (this was from a gapps zip) i noticed a mount command such as above. how can the script use busybox to mount before the system is mounted?

what if the persons phone never installed busybox in the first place?

also i looked in my /sbin folder and dont see a busybox binary. its in my /xbin directory.

obviously im missing something here. please help.